# Can we create a hard link to a symbolic link in UNIX?

Tags: unix, symlink, hardlink

I  created a symbolic link of a file and a hard link of that symbolic link. But instead of hard link `symbolic link` is being created and inodes of both of them are equal. *Is it possible to create a hard link for a symbolic link ?*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works on Linux.  We use this regularly in some mission-critical code.  As Jonathan [notes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33361702/15168), this is not guaranteed by the Posix standard, so you should double-check that it works for your system.

```
$ date >a
$ ln -s a b
$ ln b c
$ ls -li
total 4
396074 -rw-rw-r-- 1 ec2-user ec2-user 29 Oct 27 07:15 a
396345 lrwxrwxrwx 2 ec2-user ec2-user  1 Oct 27 07:16 b -> a
396345 lrwxrwxrwx 2 ec2-user ec2-user  1 Oct 27 07:16 c -> a
```

You can use the `--physical` flag to enforce this.

```
   -P, --physical
          make hard links directly to symbolic links
```

Answer (score 4):

Not reliably — as shown (demonstration on Mac OS X 10.10.5 Yosemite):

```
$ ls -l ???.c
-rw-r--r--  1 jleffler  staff  688 Oct 26 00:09 ncm.c
$ ln -s ncm.c ppp.c
$ ln ppp.c qqq.c
$ ls -l ???.c
-rw-r--r--  2 jleffler  staff  688 Oct 26 00:09 ncm.c
lrwxr-xr-x  1 jleffler  staff    5 Oct 26 23:58 ppp.c -> ncm.c
-rw-r--r--  2 jleffler  staff  688 Oct 26 00:09 qqq.c
$
```

The link follows the symlink and is created to the file at the end of the symlink, not to the symlink itself.  See the POSIX specifications of [`symlink()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/symlink.html) and (in particular) 
[`link()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/link.html).

Under `link()`, it says:

> If `path1` names a symbolic link, it is implementation-defined whether `link()` follows the symbolic link, or creates a new link to the symbolic link itself.

On Mac OS X, it follows the symbolic link.  Other systems may do it differently.